# Is possible to initiate an Intent Service from Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, intentservice

I'm trying to implementing a parallel download using a Thread, but all my unzip process should be sequentially. As is known Intent Service enqueue all pending task so in the end of all my downloads I'm trying to start a intent service. The problem is that I'm getting the following error:

```
05-30 11:49:10.520: E/AndroidRuntime(18790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 11:49:10.520: E/AndroidRuntime(18790): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service br.com.facilit.target.app.android.util.UnzipService: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class br.com.facilit.target.app.android.util.UnzipService; no empty constructor
```

My Download Thread:

```
public class DownloadService implements Runnable {

    Activity controller;
    boolean post;
    String urlParent;
    String filePath;
    String destinationPath;
    ResultReceiver mReceiver;
    String typeDownload;
    MetaDados metaDado;
    int index;
    boolean isResuming;

    File jsonFile = new File(Constants.DEST_PATH_PARENT + Constants.JSON_FILES_PATH);
    File jsonTempFile;

    public DownloadService(Activity controller, boolean post, String urlParent, String filePath,
            String destinationPath, ResultReceiver mReceiver, String typeDownload, int index, MetaDados metaDado,
            boolean isResuming) {

        this.controller = controller;
        this.post = post;
        this.urlParent = urlParent;
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.destinationPath = destinationPath;
        this.mReceiver = mReceiver;
        this.typeDownload = typeDownload;
        this.index = index;
        this.metaDado = metaDado;
        this.isResuming = isResuming;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Log.d(Constants.DOWNLOAD_AND_UNZIP_SERVICE, "Começando processo de download");

        // ALL DOWNLOAD PROCESS
        // THEN CALL INTENT FOR UNZIP

                final Intent service = new Intent(controller.getApplicationContext(), UnzipService.class);

                service.putExtra("post", false);
                service.putExtra("filePath", filePath);
                service.putExtra("destinationPath", destinationPath);
                service.putExtra("receiver", mReceiver);
                service.putExtra("typeDownload", Constants.HTML);
                service.putExtra("metaDado", metaDado);
                service.putExtra("isResuming", false);

                controller.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        controller.startService(service);

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

My Unzip Intent Service:

```
public class UnzipService extends IntentService {

    public UnzipService(String name) {
        super("UnzipService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        String filePath = intent.getStringExtra("filePath");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Log.d("UnzipService", "Simulando descompactação de arquivo " + filePath);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
       }
}
```

Manifest:

```
 <service android:name="br.com.facilit.target.app.android.util.UnzipService"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as the exception reports  you have  `no empty constructor` Change it in:

```
public UnzipService() {
        super("UnzipService");
 }
```